# Invalid Syntax CS50 Finance

Tags: python, syntax-error, cs50

I am getting a syntax error in my code:

```
 if request.method == "POST":
    quote = lookup(session["symbol"])
    name = quote["name"]
    price = float(quote["price"])

    amount = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id=:user_id", user_id = session["user_id"])
    amount = float(amount[0]["cash"]) 

    if (int(request.form.get("number")) * price) >= amount:
        return apology("You do not have enough money.")

    new_amount = db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash +: cost WHERE id =: user_id", user_id = session["user_id"], cost = quote["price"] * int(request.form.get("number"))
    db.execute("INSERT into history (userID, stockSymbol, stockName, price, amount, buySell) VALUES (:userID, :stockSymbol, :stockName, :price, :amount, 1)", userID = session["user_id"], stockSymbol = session["symbol"], stockName = name, price = quote["price"] * int(request.form.get("number"), amount = int(request.form.get("number")))

    return redirect("")

else:
    return render_template("buy.html")
```

[Click here to see my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTaA6.png)

This is where the syntax error is occurring:

`db.execute("INSERT into history (userID, stockSymbol, stockName, price, amount, buySell) VALUES (:userID, :stockSymbol, :stockName, :price, :amount, 1)", userID = session["user_id"], stockSymbol = session["symbol"], stockName = name, price = quote["price"] * int(request.form.get("number"), amount = int(request.form.get("number")))`

Could anyone explain a possible reason why?

Comment: I could, but I'm still salty because last time I answered a question of yours (also a trivial mistake) you just deleted it.

Comment: Unless someone spots the problem soon, the fastest way to get your code working would be to try it with one parameter then add the others one at a time until it goes wrong, whereupon you have found where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You miss the right parenthesis on this piece of code `quote["price"] * int(request.form.get("number"))`

Your second error is also a miss of the right parenthesis on this line `db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash +: cost WHERE id =: user_id", user_id = session["user_id"], cost = quote["price"] * int(request.form.get("number")))`

Comment: I hope that you won't delete the question.

Comment: No, no, I won't delete it.  That does help, however it is still giving me an invalid syntax error.  I deleted it last time for other reasons.

Comment: it would be better if you update your post and show the new error.

Comment: It is the same error in the same place, that is the problem.  Although what you put before will help in the future.

Comment: it is not in the same place

Comment: Correction, it is the same error in the same row.